# discord bot stocks price plotted from yfinance using pandas and save with matplotlib's savefig stacked up

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, discord.py

I'm a grade 11 student so I'm new with both python and pandas and yahoo finance so I tried to make a discord bot that can get the closed price of stocks and plotted it to send in discord for my investment discord server(best bot to use(Alpha) can't get my country stock data(Thailand - .bk) so I need to make one myself)

firstly I made data_visualization to do the job of data handling (download, plot, save, etc..)
well just

```
#this is data_visualization.py
import yfinance as yf
import pandas as pd
import datetime
from datetime import date
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
import os
from readable_table import print_info
from readable_table import print_table

def save_pic(pricegraph):
    pricefig = pricegraph.get_figure()
    pricefig.savefig('image1'+'.png')
    print('Save รูป Graph ราคา')
    return

def get_stock_price_history_and_plot_graph(ticker, range, timeframe):
    try:
        thisday = date.today()
 
        if (timeframe.lower() == "y"):
 
            start = thisday - relativedelta(years=int(range))
            _ticker = yf.download((ticker.lower()+'.bk'), start, thisday)
 
            pricegraph = _ticker['Adj Close'].plot(color=colors)
            save_pic(pricegraph)
 
            return
 
        elif(timeframe.lower() == "m"):
 
            start = thisday - relativedelta(months=int(range))
            _ticker = yf.download((ticker.lower()+'.bk'), start, thisday)
 
            pricegraph = _ticker['Adj Close'].plot(color=colors)
            save_pic(pricegraph)
            return
 
        elif(timeframe.lower() == "d"):
 
            start = thisday - relativedelta(days=int(range))
            _ticker = yf.download((ticker.lower()+'.bk'), start, thisday)
 
            pricegraph = _ticker['Adj Close'].plot(color=colors)
            save_pic(pricegraph)
            return
 
    except ValueError:
        print('Error Some Shit in Data data_visualization : get_stock_price_history_and_plot_graph')
        return
```

and then I build the bot

```
#this is bot.py
import discord
from data_visualization import get_stock_price_history_and_plot_graph as get_Stock
from data_visualization import delete_graph_pic as del_pic
from data_visualization import save_pic
from readable_table import print_info
from readable_table import print_table
 
client = discord.Client()
 
 
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('ล๊อกอินในชื่อ{0.user}'.format(client))
 
 
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
 
    else:
        lowercasemsg = message.content.lower()
        splitmsg = lowercasemsg.split(' ')
 
        if (('makima' in splitmsg[0]) or 'มากิมะ' in (splitmsg[0])):
 
            #main function
             if (len(splitmsg) > 1):
                if (splitmsg[1] == ('price') or splitmsg[1] == ('ราคา')):
                    try:
                        get_Stock(splitmsg[2], splitmsg[3], splitmsg[4])
                        await message.channel.send(
                          splitmsg[1]+splitmsg[2] + splitmsg[3]+splitmsg[4])
                        await message.channel.send(file=discord.File('image1.png'))
 
                    except ValueError:
                        message.channel.send('ข้อมูลที่กรอกมามันผิดนะ')
                        message.channel.send('เจ้าหมาโง่...')
 
              #bot run here
client.run('TOKENS')
```

everything works fine

[image: graph that was sent in discord]

but when I called it again

[image: graph stacked up]

my graph is stacked up!!!

and I think the trouble lies in data_visualization that downloaded data from yfinance stacked up in the same dataframe  but I don't know how to fix it, I can't find a solution at all

```
    def save_pic(pricegraph):
    pricefig = pricegraph.get_figure()
    pricefig.savefig('image1'+'.png')
    print('Save รูป Graph ราคา')
    return
 
#declare-basic-function
 
 
def delete_graph_pic(files):
    if os.path.exists(files):
        os.remove(files)
        return
    else:
      print(files, "does not exist")
 
 
def get_stock_price_history_and_plot_graph(ticker, range, timeframe):
    try:
        thisday = date.today()
 
        if (timeframe.lower() == "y"):
 
            start = thisday - relativedelta(years=int(range))
            _ticker = yf.download((ticker.lower()+'.bk'), start, thisday)
 
            pricegraph = _ticker['Adj Close'].plot(color=colors)
            save_pic(pricegraph)
 
            return
 
        elif(timeframe.lower() == "m"):
 
            start = thisday - relativedelta(months=int(range))
            _ticker = yf.download((ticker.lower()+'.bk'), start, thisday)
 
            pricegraph = _ticker['Adj Close'].plot(color=colors)
            save_pic(pricegraph)
            return
 
        elif(timeframe.lower() == "d"):
 
            start = thisday - relativedelta(days=int(range))
            _ticker = yf.download((ticker.lower()+'.bk'), start, thisday)
 
            pricegraph = _ticker['Adj Close'].plot(color=colors)
            save_pic(pricegraph)
            return
 
    except ValueError:
        print('Error Somethings in Data data_visualization : get_stock_price_history_and_plot_graph')
        return
```

Comment: Could you try adding this before creating the plot: "plt.clf()"? It will clear the current figure, which kinda seems to be the problem appearing here.

Comment: well it worked thank haha i know there's data stuck in there but don't know how to clear it